# Unable to delete items in React Native FlatList

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am unable to get the delete button on a custom component called `ActivityItem` to work.

Custom component in ActivityItem.js:

```
const ActivityItem = props => {
    return (
        <View>
            <Button title="Delete" onPress={props.onDelete} />
        </View>
    );
};
```

`removeActivity` function defined in the activities.js actions file:

```
export const REMOVE_ACTIVITY = 'REMOVE_ACTIVITY';

export const removeActivity = id => {
    return {type: REMOVE_ACTIVITY, id: id};
};
```

And my activities.js reducer file:

```
const initialState = {
    allActivities: ACTIVITIES,
    userActivities: ACTIVITIES.filter(activity => activity.userId === 'u1')
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    REMOVE_ACTIVITY:
        const updatedUserActivities = state.userActivities.filter((activity) => activity.id !== action.id);
        return {
            ...state,
            userActivities: updatedUserActivities
        };
    return state;
};
```

`ACTIVITIES` is a list of `Activity` items which contain `userId` and unique `id` properties.

Finally, the screen where I render a `FlatList`:

```
const MyScreen = props => {
    const myActivities = useSelector(state => state.activities.userActivities);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    return (
        <FlatList 
            data={myActivities}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id}
            renderItem={itemData => (
                <ActivityItem 
                    onDelete={() => {
                        dispatch(removeActivity(itemData.item.id));
                    }} 
                />
            )}
        />
    );
};
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: We need some debugging details. Is the value of `id` correct when it reaches the reducer?

Comment: @BrianThompson yes, I added `console.log(itemData.item.id)` after the dispatch, and pressing the delete button prints out the correct `id` associated with that `Activity` object. Is something wrong with the dispatch call or my `removeActivity()` function? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is struggling with a similar issue, make sure you are importing your action in the reducer file correctly.

Originally, I was importing like this:

```
import REMOVE_ACTIVITY from '../actions/activities';
```

Adding curly braces like this fixed the issue.

```
import { REMOVE_ACTIVITY } from '../actions/activities';
```

Comment: I'll suggest to post the complete code from next time to get a quick and better result. From your question people assume that it was imported correctly. I hope posting complete code will help you get better and quicker results :)

Answer (score 1):

> You need to change your `reducer` like this

```
const initialState = {
    allActivities: ACTIVITIES,
    userActivities: ACTIVITIES.filter(activity => activity.userId === 'u1')
};
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    REMOVE_ACTIVITY:
        const updatedUserActivities = state.userActivities.filter((activity) => activity.id !== action.id);
        return {
            ...state,
            userActivities: [...updatedUserActivities]
        };
    return state;
};
```

> you need to add `extraData` props to `flatList`, like given below for reflecting changes in `flatList`

```
const MyScreen = props => {
    const myActivities = useSelector(state => state.activities.userActivities);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    return (
        <FlatList 
            data={myActivities}
            extraData={myActivities}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id}
            renderItem={itemData => (
                <ActivityItem 
                    onDelete={() => {
                        dispatch(removeActivity(itemData.item.id));
                    }} 
                />
            )}
        />
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you need to make changes in your reducer file, that seems faulty to me. Although not much could be said by just looking at this small piece of code. I'll suggest to make changes in your reducer file so that it should look something like below:-

```
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  const { type, id } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case REMOVE_ACTIVITY:
      const { userActivities } = state.activities || {};
      const updatedUserActivities = userActivities.filter((activity) => activity.id !== id);
      console.log('updatedUserActivities is', updatedUserActivities, ' and userActivities is', userActivities);     // can use this console to check the values before updating.
      return {
          ...state,
          userActivities: updatedUserActivities,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Things changed in your reducer file was:-

- Used **userActivities** from the correct place i.e. **state.activities** instead of directly from the state.
- Corrected the switch case which works.

As suggested above in the code if you want to look what reducer is trying to update please try and print the **updatedUserActivities** and the value of **userActivities**. I hope this would fix your issue, Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately this did not solve the issue - I added the `console.log` in the reducer but nothing gets printed out when I press the delete button. Is something wrong with `onDelete` in `ActivityItem`?

Comment: @blakebullwinkel In that case you need to debug till where your code is working. Add consoles and print value of id inside action, reducer, onPress of button and onDelete of MyScreen. I think we would need more information to help you on this or maybe see more of your code. It would be helpful if you tell which consoles are working and what is getting printed in them.

Comment: Okay, so after adding some consoles I found that the reducer is not entering `REMOVE_ACTIVITY` and instead returns the default state. However, `console.log(action.type)` at the very top of the reducer prints out `REMOVE_ACTIVITY`. Do you have any idea why the `switch` statement is not working?